# A very very short riddle

Tags: riddle

Here's short riddle

> I am on three legs when I rest and on one when I work.

What am I?

Comment: As this (and a few other recent postings) goes to show, simplistic and/or chestnut riddles often make rather poor puzzles; while they have an intended "right" answer, they are way too underspecified to exclude a lot of other possibilities, and end up getting (rightly) closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that you are

> a wheelbarrow

Comment: Damn, you've been quicker.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt haha, it was a matter of seconds i suppose

Comment: Should a wheel be considered a leg?

Comment: @DEEM "Things other than legs can be considered legs" is literally the oldest rule of riddles.

Comment: @Sneftel If you call a sheep's tail a leg, how many legs does it have?  A: 4, because calling a tail a leg doesn't make it a leg.

Comment: @Jammin4CO I don't think you quite understood my comment. See http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RiddleOfTheSphinx .

Answer (score 54):

And now for something a little different

> A relay-race runner

Explanation:

> Each section of the race is known as a "leg", of which there are 4. Each runner only runs their own leg, and is waiting for the others. In other words, you rest on 3 legs, you work (run) on one.

Comment: That is rather clever

Comment: Whether this answer is right or not, it makes for a very clever riddle.  +1

Answer (score 12):

> You are an Airliner

Because

> You sit on three landing "legs" when on the tarmac between flights.  And when in flight you are always on one leg of your journey.

Answer (score 8):

> A Painting

Explanation:

> While being painted and before going "to work" it rests on an easel which usually has 3 legs.  Once it is completed and in view within a gallery or home, it hangs while working on typically 1 nail (hanger/leg).

Answer (score 7):

How about a

> person with a [Pogo Stick?](https://www.vurtegopogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/using-a-pogo-stick-for-exercise-and-training.jpg) (Would that be a Pogo Sticker? Probably not.) Image posted as a link since it's not mine.

Comment: If the pogo stick work well, the pogosticker should be on 0 leg. Wait, 1 leg. No, 0 leg. 1 leg. 0 leg... That's embarrassing.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt - so, trending towards 0.5 legs :-)

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> a wheelbarrow? (Ok it's a wheel, not a leg, but why not?)

or

> A one-legged man who sits only on three-legged stools ?

Answer (score 2):

You are

> A guitar!

Because

> When you play it's on your leg. To have it at hand- it rests on a tripod stand.

Answer (score 1):

> Road warning triangle [like this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31VBMFSJm5L.jpg)

because:

> When working it is supported by one leg. When not in use, it is probably lying on all its angles (lets call them legs)